# ClassCastException on running tests based on serenity-jbehave

Tags: maven, junit, serenity-bdd, jbehave

Getting the following error while Run as JUnit Test.

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lorg.jbehave.core.reporters.Format;
at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityJBehave.defaultConfiguration(SerenityJBehave.java:57)

    at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStories.configuration(SerenityStories.java:77)
    at org.jbehave.core.ConfigurableEmbedder.configuredEmbedder(ConfigurableEmbedder.java:118)
at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.runners.SerenityReportingRunner.<init>(SerenityReportingRunner.java:79)

    at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.runners.SerenityReportingRunner.<init>(SerenityReportingRunner.java:73)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)


    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

Comment: Noting that these aren't errors, but warnings, as the text says. First thing to check is library versions and make sure everything is running at the proper version. Then check to see if you're running the latest version of (a) JUnit and (b) your app. Then check to see if you need to update anything in your app.

Comment: But getting initializationError while executing

Comment: Then you should show *that* error as well and whatever stack trace is available. What you've shown here are warnings.

Comment: Modified the original question with errors

Comment: Same advice as original.

Comment: I have this error on JDK 11. Issue gone if get back to JDK 8

Answer (score 1):

Even I'm too late here upgrading to the latest serenity && jbehave helped me to solve the issue u mentioned. Btw I tried to do that on java 9.

```
    <serenity.version>1.9.19</serenity.version>
    <serenity.jbehave.version>1.40.0</serenity.jbehave.version> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-jbehave</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.jbehave.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```